# webpack : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

This error comes when in webpack `target = node` but i have done `target=web`(default)

also i am not loading reactjs externally

this error comes on loading app in browser

**what i am doing wrong ?**

**In Console**

[image]

**File**

[image]
[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const config = {
    target: 'web',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Instarem.com'
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**.babelrc** using

### `babel-preset-env`

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
                },
                "debug": true,
                "modules": "commonjs"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

thanks :)

> **I found Clue**

---

*In facebook's **[create react app generator](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)** bundle it shows*

```
module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! ./lib/React */ "./node_modules/react/lib/React.js");
```

*but in my case it shows only*

```
module.exports = require("react");
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should not use

```
externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

in web app. According to https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals it is only for backend. Since you use `nodeExternals` in web app you get CommonJS modules, that expects built in node `require` function. So just remove it to fix error.

Comment: i am using `babel-preset-env`instead of `babel-preset-es2015` both almost do same thing  .just `babel-preset-env` does little bit more .so at a time only one should be used

Comment: @vijay see my updated answer. I reproduced ypur config and it is working as expected without `nodeExternals`.

Comment: I just had the exact same problem and had indeed nodeExternals() placed inside the config targeting web.

Comment: damn I lost 1 hour because I forgot that after cloning webpack config from a Node Typescript project 

Answer (score 9):

My issue was in my package.json, I had to remove

`"type":"module"`

It was trying to load the file as an es6 module

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_type

Comment: very good haloooo

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem a few minutes ago. This usually happens when you mix up the `target` property for the bundle in **webpack.config** file. E.g. if you are creating a bundle for React the target should be `target: 'web'` and should not include anything relating to node like `'async-node'` or `'node'`.

```
const reactConfig = {
   name: 'React Bundle',
   target: 'web',
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone. Add into call nodeExternals option importType with value 'umd'.

```
nodeExternals({
   importType: 'umd'
})
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

I set this config up (minus the extraneous things that seem to be specific to your env) locally and it worked.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

---

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
        },
        "debug": true,
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

**webpack.config.js**

```
const config = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="root" />
    <script src=" ./build/main.bundle.js "></script>
</body>
```

Running npm start built the bundle and running index.html ran the react app.

Comment: i am already using `babel-preset-env`.you can see in .babelrc

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `webpack` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, try to **remove** `<script src="./src/app.js"></script>` from `index.html`