# Cannot resolve 'child_process' in Stripe, fixes lead to require being undefined

Tags: webpack, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe with my application, when I do, I get this error during build:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'PATH\node
>   _modules\stripe\lib'

When I change my webpack dev config to target node like this:

```
export default {
  ...,
  target: 'node',
  ...
}
```

I get an error with require not being defined, which everywhere online indicates is caused by the following statement which is not in my webpack config:

```
externals: [nodeExternals()]
```

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818937/webpack-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `stripe` from `npm` in your frontend application. But this package is a server-side package. You can't integrate it in your client-side code (like React/Angular), you must use it server-side with for example Node.js.

You will find great explanation on how to include stripe on the client side here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs

Comment: can you show where specifically, you linked an incredibly long documentation link